# Binary XML file line #18 in mypackage:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-navigation

This error occurs when I, after adding "Context context" property to the adapter constructor, try to pass "getContext()" argument to the adapter instance I create in the Fragment.
Completely no idea what to do, some decisions I found in SO did not help.
I will deeply appreciate any advice.

Error text:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{space.rodionov.swedishdriller/space.rodionov.swedishdriller.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18 in space.rodionov.swedishdriller:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #18 in space.rodionov.swedishdriller:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
```

In fragment:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class DrillerFragment : Fragment(R.layout.cardstack_layout), CardStackListener {

    private val viewModel: DrillerViewModel by viewModels()
    private var drillerAdapter = JavaDrillerAdapter(JavaDrillerAdapter.JavaDrillerDiff(), false, requireContext())
```

In adapter:

```
public class JavaDrillerAdapter extends ListAdapter<Word, JavaDrillerAdapter.JavaDrillerViewHolder> {

    private Boolean nativToForeign;

    Context context;

    protected JavaDrillerAdapter(@NonNull DiffUtil.ItemCallback diffCallback, Boolean nativToForeign, Context context) {
    super(diffCallback);
    this.nativToForeign = nativToForeign;
    this.context = context;
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        //blablabla
        />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView //THIS IS THE LINE #18 THE ERROR REFERS TO
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        //blablabla

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) // THIS IS ALSO THE LINE MENTIONED IN THE ERROR

        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.findNavController()
        // and so on
```

Comment: Do you have the same behavior if you transfered this instantiation in `onCreateView`

Comment: thanks, I moved it and everythng works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to move your adapter initialization in the `onCreate` method, the `context` is unavailable before views initialization:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class DrillerFragment : Fragment(R.layout.cardstack_layout), CardStackListener {

    private val viewModel: DrillerViewModel by viewModels()
    private var drillerAdapter: JavaDrillerAdapter? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        drillerAdapter = JavaDrillerAdapter(JavaDrillerAdapter.JavaDrillerDiff(), false, requireContext())
    }
```